# MATLAB clear current figure

Tags: matlab

I want to clear MATLAB's global `CurrentFigure` property, because I need a plot that I make to not be overwritten if a careless user uses `plot` without opening a new figure. I tried

```
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', []);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is this impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this doesn't work.

What does work is `set(myFigureHandle,'HandleVisibility','off')`. This way, the figure with the handle `myFigureHandle` will not become the current figure anymore.

To be really safe, you may want to set the axes' handle visibility to `'off'`, which will hide them from `gca`. In order to plot into these axes, you'll have to use `plot(myAxesHandle,...)`, though, i.e. you have to explicitly point to the axes if you want to plot there.